# Google Analytics Behavior when Calling trackPageview Twice

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site using Google Analytics. On one page clicking a button changes everything about the page.  However, it does not change the page's URL. I would like to track it as a separate page in Google Analytics. So I would assume I would `trackPageview("/new")` *(or really `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',"/new");`)*, **however before I implement this I want to make sure events and such are not counted twice.**

That is to say, if I were to load the page `/` (and have the default trackPageview call occur) then call `trackPageview("/new")` and finally call `trackEvent("Test",…)` would the `Test` event be reflected on the `/`, `/new` or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, 'Test' would be reflected on '/' because that is the window.location.pathname.

There is an undocumented GA function called _set where you can override the variable like the code below:

```
_gaq.push(['_set','page','/new']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
$("#submit-button).click(function () {
   _gaq.push(['_trackevent']); // tracks to '/new'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing it looks as though the `Test` event shows up on `/` regardless of pushing a new pageview.